# Fix the Scrolling of Hub Control in Windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I have used Hub control in my Windows Phone 8.1 WinRT App.

I am dynamically populating the HubSections.

I don't want to go to last Hubsection once I have reached first Hubsection and same thing applies for Last Hubsection.

Default behaviour of Hub is that it scrolls from first Hubsection to last Hubsection.

Please Help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are looking for [FlipView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.flipview) add content in it using [FlipViewItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.controls.flipviewitem.aspx).

Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a method like
panHub_SectionsInViewChanged(object sender, SectionsInViewChangedEventArgs e)
where in your xaml you have:

```
<Hub x:Name="panHub" Style="{StaticResource HubPanoramaStyle}" Margin="0, 0, 0, 0"
                 SectionsInViewChanged="panHub_SectionsInViewChanged" Loaded="panHub_Loaded" Grid.RowSpan="2">
```

Then the SectionsInViewChangedEventArgs e will have sections that moved into view and those out.

You could try scrolling to the last section if you are going from Last to First, like panHub.ScrollToSection(LastSection);